# C#, Interop.Excel, Max rows per worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, rows

I have a C# application (.Net 4.5) that exports data to Excel. My application uses Interop version 15, which equates to Excel 2013. Within Excel 2013, I can have over 1 million rows per worksheet, but the Interop will only accept just over 64,000 rows, otherwise it crashes.

Does anyone know if there is a work-around for this or do I need to upgrade both Excel and the Interop to a more recent version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend not using Interop. Use something like `EPPlus` to export the data: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

Comment: Thanks for that - looks interesting. Is EPPlus significantly faster than the Interop? One other issue I have, which I didn't mention, is how slow the Interop is.

Comment: EPPlus is faster, less memory and CPU intensive. It doesn't require the user to have Excel installed on their machine. Interop works by basically spinning up an Excel instance in the background (you can see this if you look at running processes when you call the library) then your code is calling that process to create the Excel file. EPPlus is writing a file directly to disk. If you don't want/can't buy a commercial licence but want to use commercially, I think version 4.5.3 is the last which is available under a free commercial use licence. I am in no way affiliated with EPPlus.